# Debugpy don't work "no suitable test method found"

Tags: python, neovim, debugpy

I have installed neovim as my IDE and i configured it with this video "the perfect neovim setup with python" from 'Dreams of code" but the when i enter 'space+dpr' i have the messege "no suitable test method found"
How can i solve it.
2 .
When i write `:checkhealth` i have `"WARNING {nvim-lspconfig}: overriding <config>"`

Has it a relation with the problem above

I have tried every thing , i searched in github in Reddit and nothing found